# How can I check if a vote for server has been counted?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make a minecraft server voting system where when you vote for the server for example here: [Minecraft servers list](http://minecraft-server-list.com/) You will get certain points for a successful vote. The question is how to check if a player has successfully voted for server or not? Anyway to check the string of "Your vote has been successful" or something? Thank you for your answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On JS side, do an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) request when the user vote, and then wait for a callback after the server responded, then you can write "Vote successful" or other stuff.

On Server side (no matter if this is php or another language), you'll have to store information about the request, like user IP, to prevent him for multiple votes.

You could also store this information in a cookie on the client side, or in the local storage, but it can easily be cleaned by the user.

Or even, associate the vote with an email, and associate the email with the request.

I don't know anyway if there is a definitive solution to prevent multiple votes in this case, because user can create new mail account, modify its IP, go through a proxy, ... Best way is create an auth mechanism that will force each user to be auth before voting, I guess.

This post only exposes concepts anyway because your question is quite too large to answer it exactly here.

Comment: anyway to do it via php? And also I did not fully understand how would I check if the vote was successful or not? And I already have an auth mechanism I just need to check if the vote was counted or not

Comment: From the JS, you'll send an AJAX request, the server will receive it. If it's php, then the php will do its thing, then compute a response that it will send back to JS, a s JSON object for example "{ "vote" : "successful" }, then a callback function will be triggered in your JS, receiving the JSON object as parameter.

Comment: I'm new to AJAX and JS, can you show it via code and explain it please? I have read your link to AJAX but I still don't get it... If you can't it's ok, I will try to find the way....